# how to get the facebook friends of any user

Tags: php, ajax, facebook, api

`GET` calls to the url http://www.facebook.com/ajax/typeahead_friends.php?u=${USER ID}&__a=1 (replace ${USER ID}) seem to get the friends list of that user.  Is there an ``official'' way of doing this, i.e. through the documented facebook APIs?

Comment: try `$facebook->api('{$userid}/friends');`

Answer (score 1):

A more "offical" way is to use the [Graph api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).